# MySQL full-text search not returning as expected

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, where-clause

I'm having big trouble trying to find a solution to a table search.

Table:

```
ID | NAME | DESCRIPTION | APPLICATION | BRAND | SUPPLIER_PRODUCT_ID | SUPPLIER_ID
```

Definition:

```
int,text,text,text,text,varchar(55),int
```

This table is filled with products data gathered from different suppliers' databases.

I need to create a search by different words like:

```
 'BUJE BARRA CHEVROLET CORSA' (1 & 2 NAME OR DESCRIPTION, 3 & 4 APPLICATION)
```

or

```
 'PASTILLA FRENO CORSA FRASLE' (1 & 2 NAME OR DESCRIPTION, 3 APPLICATION, 4 BRAND)
```

or

```
 'FR44451MX' (= SUPPLIER_PRODUCT_ID)
```

or

```
'PARRILLA CORSA' (1 NAME OR DESCRIPTION, 2 APPLICATION)
```

I've created an stored procedure to separate each word and returning then into a temporary table but I cannot find the right solution. I think the problem is with data, but I cannot change it.
For example, same products from different suppliers have different NAMEs or DESCRIPTIONs:

```
    'AMORTIGUADOR DELANTERO' NAME
    'DELANTERO DERECHO' DESCRIPTION
    'CHEVROLET CORSA' BRAND
    'FR44451MX' SUPPLIER_PRODUCT_ID
    '1' SUPPLIER_ID
```

and other supplier:

```
    'AMORTIGUADOR' NAME
    'DELANTERO CHEVROLET CORSA' DESCRIPTION
    'NULL' BRAND
    'FR-44451' SUPPLIER_PRODUCT_ID
    '2' SUPPLIER_ID
```

I need the search that returns every product from every supplier matching the search words.

***UPDATE 1***

I created a function that I've found here to split the string:

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE FUNCTION 
   FN_SPLIT_STRING ( pSTRING TEXT , pDELIMITER CHAR(1) , pPOSITION INT)
   RETURNS TEXT
   DETERMINISTIC -- always returns same results for same input parameters
    BEGIN

        DECLARE N INT ;

        -- get max number of items
        SET N = LENGTH(pSTRING) - LENGTH(REPLACE(pSTRING, pDELIMITER, '')) + 1;

        IF pPOSITION > N THEN
            RETURN NULL ;
        ELSE
            RETURN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pSTRING, pDELIMITER, pPOSITION) , pDELIMITER , -1 ) ;        
        END IF;
    END$

DELIMITER ;
```

And in my WHERE clause, I use the following:

```
WHERE P.NAME LIKE CONCAT(FN_SPLIT_STRING(pFILTER, '|', 1),' %', FN_SPLIT_STRING(pFILTER, '|', 2), '%') 
    AND (P.APPLICATION LIKE CONCAT('%', FN_SPLIT_STRING(pFILTER, '|', 3), '%') OR (P.NAME LIKE CONCAT('%', FN_SPLIT_STRING(pFILTER, '|', 3), '%'))) 
    AND P.BRAND LIKE CONCAT('%', FN_SPLIT_STRING(pFILTER, '|', 4), '%')
    AND S.BUSINESS_NAME LIKE 
        CASE 
            WHEN FN_SPLIT_STRING(pFILTER, '|', 5) != '' 
            THEN  CONCAT(FN_SPLIT_STRING(pFILTER, '|', 5),'%')
            ELSE '%%'
        END
```

The results are perfect, but the performance is not good. 
Can I do the same with FULL-TEXT indexes?

Comment: Please add some sample data, the queries that you tried but that do not return the result you expect, the result you get and the result you expect (based on the sample data). It's also a bit unclear what your search input actually looks like (although your examples show only one continuous input string, I assume you have 3 input fields that each specify different columns to search in), but that might get clearer if you add some results (along with the corresponding input).

Comment: It is just one input with different words as I posted.
I've tried with where and likes, that's why I'm asking for help using full-text search, because it's almost impossible doing it the way I've tried.

Comment: I've tried `WHERE MATCH(NAME,DESCRIPTION) AGAINST(WORD1 IN BOOLEAN MODE)` and the same with other words